# converting from lexeme to token in Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I'm running the chunk of code under 3. Word to Vectors Integration from [this NLP tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/04/natural-language-processing-made-easy-using-spacy-%E2%80%8Bin-python/). It uses Spacy's lexemes to calculate the most similar words to whatever word you give it - I'm using it to try to find the nearest synonyms to the given word. However, if you replace apple with a word like "look" you get a lot of related words, but not synonyms (examples: pretty, there, over, etc.). I was thinking of modifying the code to also filter by part of speech, so that I could just get verbs in the output and would be able to go from that. To do that, I'd need to use tokens so I can use token.pos_, since that function isn't available for lexemes. Does anyone know a way to take the output (list called "others" in the code) and change it from a lexeme to a token? I was reading over spacy's information document for lexemes [here](https://spacy.io/api/lexeme), but I haven't been able to find anything about transforming.

I've also tried adding a section of code at the end to the other person's code:

```
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
parser = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
my_word = u'calm'
#Generate word vector of the word - apple
apple = parser.vocab[my_word]
#Cosine similarity function
cosine = lambda v1, v2: dot(v1, v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2))
others = list({w for w in parser.vocab if w.has_vector and w.orth_.islower() 
and w.lower_ != my_word})
print("done listing")
# sort by similarity score
others.sort(key=lambda w: cosine(w.vector, apple.vector))
others.reverse()
for word in others[:10]:
print(word.orth_)
```

The part I added:

```
b = ""
for word in others[:10]:

    a = str(word) + ' '
    b += a

doc = nlp(b)
print(doc)
token = doc[0]

counter = 1

while counter < 50:
    token += doc[counter]
    counter += 1

print(token)
```

This is the output error:

```
'token += doc[counter]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'spacy.tokens.token.Token' and 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'
<spacy.lexeme.Lexeme object at 0x000002920ABFAA68> <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme object at 0x000002920BD56EE8>  '
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix what I did or another way to change the lexeme to a token? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Doc to get a Token, as the Token doesn't own any data -- it's just a view. So, you could do something like:

```
doc = Doc(lex.vocab, words=[lex.orth_])
```